# How do I get an ID or String which is unique for every user/pc in Java?

Tags: java, javadoc

I'm looking for a unique ID or String to identify users or PC's.
I'm creating a Java script with a security method which uses a unique ID or String.
I used the MAC Address before, but since an update at the developers I'm coding for, this isn't allowed anymore. Is there another way to get some sort of unique ID to identify users or pc's which is allowed? For more information: I'm coding for RSBot, which is an open-source program which runs user created Java scripts.

Thanks in advance,
Kevin.

Comment: Would the IP address be of any use?

Answer (score 0):

See `java.util.UUID`, specifically:

```
UUID.randomUUID();
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html#randomUUID()

Note that this is random, but not *reproducible*.  If you need to be able to generate the same ID over and over on the same computer this is not what you need.

Comment: Yes, I need an ID which can be reproduced over and over again.

Comment: How about saving the UUID in on the server and in a cookie on the client?

Comment: Wouldn't this be easy to bypass?

Comment: Most times all you need is to have _stored_ the UUID, so that it can be sent again.  reproducibility only matters if you have no secure means to store the UUID.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to look at JUG -

GUUIDs based on the Ethernet device, random, time, etc

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome

Comment: Yes, it uses java.util.UUID, but it also illustrates seeding it with other information besides the standard random call.  It's unclear what is allowed/unallowed in the OP's post, so yes - just something to look at.

Comment: Is it possible to use this JUG method without importing a .jar file? Because other people need to run this script too, and if they don't have that .jar the script'll crash.

Answer (score 0):

[OSHI](https://github.com/oshi/oshi) is a free JNA-based (native) Operating System and Hardware Information library for Java. It does not require the installation of any additional native libraries.
Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
    <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

You can retrieve system information, such as OS id, CPU id, baseboard id etc.
Then just combine id-s to generate PC UUID:

```
public String getUID() {
    final byte[] rawInput = StringUtils
            .joinWith(hardwareLayer.getProcessor().getProcessorID(),
                    hardwareLayer.getComputerSystem().getBaseboard().getSerialNumber(),
                    ... )
            .getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    try {
        return UUID.nameUUIDFromBytes(rawInput).toString().toUpperCase();
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        logger.error(e);
        return StringUtils.EMPTY;
    }
}
```